# AVPlayer Pan Gesture not Working on iOS 13

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios13, avplayerviewcontroller

I am working on Xamarin Forms Project where users can navigate to list of playlists and then preview them. During preview, users can swipe between the videos. On iOS 12 everything is working fine but on iOS 13 it is not working.

In debug mode we observed on error in the console

**Error**

```
[] nw_endpoint_flow_copy_multipath_subflow_counts Called on non-Multipath connection
0000000A:  0100  4          4           66
00000016:  0101  4          4           66
00000022:  0102  3          6          110
0000002E:  011A  5          8          116
0000003A:  011B  5          8          124
00000046:  0128  3          2            3
00000052:  0131  2         12          132
0000005E:  0132  2         20          144
000000A6:  0100  4          4          256
000000B2:  0101  4          4          256
000000BE:  0102  3          6          266
000000CA:  0103  3          2            6
000000D6:  0106  3          2            6
000000E2:  0115  3          2            3
000000EE:  0201  4          4          272
000000FA:  0202  4          4         7818*
```

Here is the Custom Renderer Code for AV Player

```
using AVFoundation;
using AVKit;
using CoreFoundation;
using CoreMedia;
using Project.Controls.Video;
using Project.iOS.Renderers;
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(VideoPlayer), typeof(VideoPlayerRenderer))]
namespace Project.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class VideoPlayerRenderer : ViewRenderer<VideoPlayer, UIView>
    {
        AVPlayer player;
        AVPlayerItem playerItem;
        AVPlayerViewController _playerViewController;       // solely for ViewController property
        AVAsset asset;
        NSObject didPlayToEndObserver;

        public override UIViewController ViewController => _playerViewController;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<VideoPlayer> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    // Create AVPlayerViewController
                    _playerViewController = new AVPlayerViewController();

                    // Set Player property to AVPlayer
                    player = new AVPlayer();
                    _playerViewController.Player = player;

                    UITapGestureRecognizer uiTapGestureRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer(TapAction);
                    _playerViewController.ContentOverlayView.GestureRecognizers = new UIGestureRecognizer[] { uiTapGestureRecognizer };

                    //UIPanGestureRecognizer uIPanGestureRecognizer = new UIPanGestureRecognizer(TapAction);
                    //_playerViewController.ContentOverlayView.GestureRecognizers = new UIGestureRecognizer[] { uIPanGestureRecognizer };

                    var x = _playerViewController.View;

                    // Use the View from the controller as the native control
                    SetNativeControl(_playerViewController.View);

                    didPlayToEndObserver = AVPlayerItem.Notifications.ObserveDidPlayToEndTime(AVPlayerItem_DidPlayToEndTimeNotification);
                }

                SetAreTransportControlsEnabled();
                SetSource();

                e.NewElement.UpdateStatus += OnUpdateStatus;
                e.NewElement.PlayRequested += OnPlayRequested;
                e.NewElement.PauseRequested += OnPauseRequested;
                e.NewElement.StopRequested += OnStopRequested;
                e.NewElement.VolumeMute += OnMute;
                e.NewElement.VolumeUnmute += OnUnmute;
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                e.OldElement.UpdateStatus -= OnUpdateStatus;
                e.OldElement.PlayRequested -= OnPlayRequested;
                e.OldElement.PauseRequested -= OnPauseRequested;
                e.OldElement.StopRequested -= OnStopRequested;
                e.OldElement.VolumeMute -= OnMute;
                e.OldElement.VolumeUnmute -= OnUnmute;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == VideoPlayer.AreTransportControlsEnabledProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                SetAreTransportControlsEnabled();
            }
            else if (e.PropertyName == VideoPlayer.SourceProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                SetSource();
            }
            else if (e.PropertyName == VideoPlayer.PositionProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                TimeSpan controlPosition = ConvertTime(player.CurrentTime);

                if (Math.Abs((controlPosition - Element.Position).TotalSeconds) > 1)
                {
                    player.Seek(CMTime.FromSeconds(Element.Position.TotalSeconds, 1));
                }
            }
        }

        void SetAreTransportControlsEnabled()
        {
            ((AVPlayerViewController)ViewController).ShowsPlaybackControls = Element.AreTransportControlsEnabled;
        }

        void SetSource()
        {
            if (Element.Source is UriVideoSource)
            {
                string uri = (Element.Source as UriVideoSource).Uri;
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri))
                    asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(new NSUrl(uri));
            }
            else if (Element.Source is FileVideoSource)
            {
                string uri = (Element.Source as FileVideoSource).File;
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri))
                    asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(new NSUrl(uri));
            }
            else if (Element.Source is ResourceVideoSource)
            {
                string path = (Element.Source as ResourceVideoSource).Path;
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
                {
                    string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                    string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(path).Substring(1);
                    NSUrl url = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource(filename, extension, directory);
                    asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(url);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (player != null)
                {
                    player.Pause();
                    player.CancelPendingPrerolls();
                    player.ReplaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(null);
                }
                if (playerItem != null)
                {
                    playerItem.CancelPendingSeeks();
                    playerItem.Dispose();
                    playerItem = null;
                }
                if (asset != null)
                {
                    asset.CancelLoading();
                    asset.Dispose();
                    asset = null;
                }
            }

            if (asset != null)
            {
                string[] keys = { "playable" };

                asset.LoadValuesAsynchronously(keys, () =>
                {
                    DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
                    {
                        if (asset == null) return;

                        playerItem = new AVPlayerItem(asset);
                        player.ReplaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(playerItem);
                        if (playerItem != null && Element.AutoPlay)
                            player.Play();
                    });
                });
            }
        }

        private void TapAction()
        {
            this.Element?.InvokeOnTapEvent();
        }

        // Event handler to update status
        void OnUpdateStatus(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            VideoStatus videoStatus = VideoStatus.NotReady;

            switch (player.Status)
            {
                case AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay:
                    switch (player.TimeControlStatus)
                    {
                        case AVPlayerTimeControlStatus.Playing:
                            videoStatus = VideoStatus.Playing;
                            break;

                        case AVPlayerTimeControlStatus.Paused:
                            videoStatus = VideoStatus.Paused;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            ((IVideoPlayerController)Element).Status = videoStatus;

            if (playerItem != null)
            {
                ((IVideoPlayerController)Element).Duration = ConvertTime(playerItem.Duration);
                ((IElementController)Element).SetValueFromRenderer(VideoPlayer.PositionProperty, ConvertTime(playerItem.CurrentTime));
            }
        }

        TimeSpan ConvertTime(CMTime cmTime)
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Double.IsNaN(cmTime.Seconds) ? 0 : cmTime.Seconds);
        }

        // Event handlers to implement methods
        void OnPlayRequested(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            player.Play();
        }

        void OnPauseRequested(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            player.Pause();
        }

        void OnStopRequested(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            player.Pause();
            player.Seek(new CMTime(0, 1));
        }

        void OnMute(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            player.Volume = 0;
        }

        void OnUnmute(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            player.Volume = 1;
        }

        private void AVPlayerItem_DidPlayToEndTimeNotification(object sender, NSNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            player.Pause();
            player.Seek(new CMTime(0, 1));

            Element?.InvokePlayCompleted();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (asset != null)
                {
                    asset.CancelLoading();
                    asset.Dispose();
                    asset = null;
                }

                if (player != null)
                {
                    player.Pause();
                    player.ReplaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(null);
                    player.Dispose();
                    player = null;
                }

                if (playerItem != null)
                {
                    playerItem.Dispose();
                    playerItem = null;
                }

                if (_playerViewController != null)
                {
                    _playerViewController.Dispose();
                    _playerViewController = null;
                }

                if (Element != null)
                {
                    Element.UpdateStatus -= OnUpdateStatus;
                    Element.PlayRequested -= OnPlayRequested;
                    Element.PauseRequested -= OnPauseRequested;
                    Element.StopRequested -= OnStopRequested;
                    Element.VolumeMute -= OnMute;
                    Element.VolumeUnmute -= OnUnmute;
                }

                if (didPlayToEndObserver != null)
                    didPlayToEndObserver.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An Error message and Stacktrace would make lives a whole lot easier!!

Comment: Hi , only Pan Gesture not Working on iOS 13 and other function is OK , right ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes only Pan Gesture is not working

Comment: @FreakyAli : I posted the error message . AVPlayer  Functionality is working without any error. The only thing missing is Swiping between multiple videos